# How to avoid append char from magnetic stripe reader to JTextArea in java

Tags: java, swing, magnetic-cards

I want allow to append char only from keyboard text not a magnetic strip text.

```
setfocusable(false) 

setEnabled(false)
```

above both options are not allowed also keyboard inputs.

Here is my code

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
  import javax.swing.JDialog;
  import javax.swing.JTextArea;

  public class JTextAreaMSR extends JDialog {
        private JTextArea input;

        JTextAreaMSR() {
            super();
            setModal(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JTextAreaMSR jtA = new JTextAreaMSR();
            jtA.input = new JTextArea();
            jtA.input.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
            jtA.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jtA.add(jtA.input);
            jtA.setSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
            jtA.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jtA.input.addKeyListener(jtA.new MyKeyListener());
            jtA.setVisible(true);
        }

        class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyTyped : " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyPressed : " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyReleased : " + e.getKeyChar());
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I restrict magnetic strip inputs only ?

Comment: How you add the text to your text area? Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand, what's wrong in your code.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy

How you add the text to your text area?
 Whenever swipe a card through magnetic strip , it will append char to current focus area(Similar keyboard event)

 Is possible to identify where to come inputs (keyboard or magnetic strip) ?

Comment: I still don't see your code. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I think the card reader acts as a keyboard for the OS. That might be the problem...

Comment: @keuleJ
Exactly card reader acts as a keyboard.
But we need to differentiate input type.
There is any possibilities ?  
Time different fail some cases.

Comment: Well i don't think you can decide from which keyboard the input came. Maybe you can identify the format of the string or something?

Comment: @keuleJ Input text via MSR start char '%' and end char '\n'. But , able to type those char keyboard also

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Am updated my question with code.

 KeyListener (all methods )called both keyboard and magnetic strip reader

Comment: Maybe check the KeyEvent, perhaps it has a value to indicate the source.

Comment: @matt
e.getSource() return JTextArea

Comment: What about getLocation, or getModifiers. There are a bunch of fields/values that can be checked.

Comment: @matt e.getModifiers return 0/1.
Both msr and keyboard